# вопрос по дружественным функциям класса

Tags: c++

Изучаю с++, есть вопрос:

Есть класс:

```
#ifndef STRING_2_H
#define STRING_2_H

#include <iostream>

class String
{
private:
   char *str;
   int len;
   static int num_strings;
   static const int CINLIM = 80;
public:
   String(const char * s);
   String();
   String(const String &);
   ~String();
   String & operator+(const String &);
   String & stringlow();
   String & stringup(); 
   int has(const char) const;
   bool operator==(const String &);
   String & operator=(const String &);
   friend String & operator+(const char *, const String &);
   friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, const String & a);
   friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream &, String &);
};



#endif
```

есть реализация методов класса, правда немного недописанная:

```
#include "string2.h"
#include <cstring>




String::String()
{
    str = new char[1];
    *str = '\0';
    len = 0;
//  num_strings++;
}



String::String(const char * s)
{
    len = strlen(s) + 1;
    str = new char[len];
    strcpy(str, s);
//  num_strings++;
}

String::String(const String & a)
{
    len = a.len;
    str = new char[len];
    strcpy(str, a.str);
//  num_strings++;
}

String::~String()
{
//  num_strings--;
//std::cout << "Dest" << num_strings << std::endl;
delete [] str;
}


String & String::operator+(const String & a)
{
     std::cout << "debug1";
     char * buffer;
     buffer = new char [len + a.len + 1];
     strcpy(buffer, str);
     String res(strcat(buffer, a.str));
     delete [] buffer;
     std::cout << "debug1";
     return res;
}

String & String::stringlow()
{

}

String & String::stringup()
{

}


int String::has(const char a) const
{

}


 bool String::operator==(const String &)
{


}


String & String::operator=(const String & a) 
{
    if(this == &a)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    //std::cout << a;
    std::cout << "debug10";
    len = a.len;
    delete [] str;
    str = new char[len];
    strcpy(str, a.str);
    return *this;   
}

String & operator+(const char *a, const String & b)
{
    std::cout << "debug2";
}


std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const String & a)
{
    os << a.str;
    return os;
}


std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & is, String & a)
{
    char *buffer;
    buffer = new char[String::CINLIM];
    is.getline(buffer, String::CINLIM);
    a = buffer; 
    delete [] buffer;
    return is;
}
```

Основная программа такая:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "string2.h"
int main()
{
    String s1(" and I am a C++ student.");
    String s2 = "Please enter your name: ";
    String s3;
    cout << s2;
    cin >> s3;
    std::cout << "cout";
    s2 = "My name is " + s3;
    cout << "Bye\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Есть вывод компилятора

> ~/workspace/learning_c++$ ./a.out  Please enter your name: Bla
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>   what():  std::bad_alloc debug10coutdebug2debug10Аварийный останов
>   (сделан дамп памяти)

Непонятно, где ошибка.

Непонятно еще следующее: 
у нас есть строка `s2 = "bla bla" + s3;`
Почему по выводу в консоль первым вызывается оператор= когда по приоритету он ниже чем +?
Как я понял, в с++ существуют конструкторы преобразования - один из них - `String::String(const char * s)`. Почему компилятор требует именно дружественную функцию с чар и стринг в аргументах, а не преобразовывает чар в стринг и оттуда в оператор+(стринг)?

Comment: Я не могу предположить куда идёт вызов из оператора `>>` при операции `=`. Если уж так взялись за классы - трассируйте - и найдёте ошибку быстро. Могу точно сказать что первым вызывается оператор `>>` в строке `cin >> s3;`

Comment: Скорее всего у вас ошибка логическая. Она затрагивает несколько строк тут `is.getline(buffer, String::CINLIM);` и тут `a = buffer;` (оператор `>>` вызов конструктора) и тут `len = strlen(s) + 1;` (конструктор), и заключается она в том, что вы в getline получаете "буфер", т.е. не ASCIIZ, а делая присваивание, вызываете методы работы с ASCIIZ. Возможно поможет поставить `buffer[is.getline(buffer, String::CINLIM)]=0`, но при len=80 ловите глюк, тогда надо в new +1 поставить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом предложении

```
s2 = "My name is " + s3;
```

у вас вызывается дружественный классу оператор, как наиболее подходящая функция для заданных аргументов, где не требуется их преобразование

```
friend String & operator+(const char *, const String &);
```

Этот оператор определен следующим образом

```
String & operator+(const char *a, const String & b)
{
    std::cout << "debug2";
}
```

Этот оператор не имеет предложения с `return`, поэтому программа имеет неопределенное поведение при вызове этого оператора.

Правильно бы было объявить этот оператор как

```
String operator+(const char *a, const String & b);
```

то есть чтобы из него возвращался временный объект.

Comment: это был ключевой момент недопонимания, спасибо!

Comment: @Ivan Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Comment: А какой компилятор разрешает скомпилировать код функции, которая якобы что-то возвращает, без оператора `return` и как это соотносится со стандартом?

Comment: @Harry Практически, все компиляторы, с которыми я имел дело, пропускают в отдельных случаях подобное определение функции, что ведет к неопределенному поведению программы. Конечно это не имеет отношения к main.

Comment: Ну, из своей практики я был уверен, что такой код просто не будет скомпилирован. Ну в самом крайнем случае - с огромными буквами предупреждением :) Странно, что такое вообще разрешено - тем более что в этом случае отследить компилятору нарушение легче легкого. И - возврат чего-то, что не будет использовано - как по мне, никак не основание для того, чтобы разрешить такое поведение в стандарте. Так сказать, ищу и не нахожу никакого оправдания; рад, что те компиляторы, с какими приходилось иметь дело мне, считают это безусловной ошибкой...

Comment: @Harry Я постоянно наталкиваюсь на вопросы на SO, где спрашивают, почему программа не работает корректно, в то время как причиной этого является именно то, что забыли возвратить значение из функции.

Answer (score 2):

У вас выполнение идет в таком порядке:
Два конструктора от `const char *`.
Конструктор по умолчанию для `s3`.
Оператор вывода.
Оператор ввода, в котором выполняется конструктор от `const char *` для приведения типа, затем присваивания.
Ваш вывод `"cout"`.
Оператор `+`. В котором нет никакого кода. Он вызывается, как идеально :) точно подходящий под выражение `const char* + String&`, в то время как другой оператор требовал бы дополнительного приведения типа.

Не знаю, какую затычку вы поместили в этот оператор присваивания, но он у вас

```
String & operator+(const char *a, const String & b)
```

Ссылку на что он может возвращать? На `b`? Нельзя. константа. На вновь создаваемую строку в операторе? Нельзя, эта строка будет уничтожена, ссылка в никуда. Не возвращать ничего? :) Компилятор не пропустит.

Вот тут вы что-то нам недоговариваете... и получаете проблемы с памятью.

Или вы выбрасываете свободный оператор конкатенации, заставляя тем самым использовать оператор `+` в составе класса. У которого те же проблемы, о которых вам честно должен сообщить компилятор - о возвращении ссылки на **локальную** переменную `res`.

```
 String res(strcat(buffer, a.str));
 delete [] buffer;
 std::cout << "debug1\n";
 return res;
```

Переменная `res` при выходе будет уничтожена. К какой памяти будет обращаться присваивание строки переменной `s2`? К освобожденной, может, перезаписанной и т.д. Словом, undefined behaviour.

Так что у вас все четко - что написали, то и получили...

Answer (score 1):

> Почему компилятор требует именно дружественную функцию с чар и стринг в аргументах, а не преобразовывает чар в стринг и оттуда в оператор+(стринг)?

Он не требует, а смотрит, какие есть возможные варианты. И выбирает тот из них, какой лучше соответствует передаваемым аргументам. Если есть несколько вариантов одинаковой "лучшести", будет сообщено о невозможности выбрать подходящий.